# 35 working days since UK visit visa was applied for. 2 'escalations', absolutely no contact

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

This is clearly highly unusual given that people in my country are currently being issued their visit visas within 10-15 days.

I was told to wait 15 working days after the first escalation (20 days after application date), and that has now elapsed and the only answer I'm getting from the call center is that a decision still hasn't been made and there's nothing I can do.

This is bizarre. Is there anyone else I can contact to find out what's going on or to relay the urgent circumstances they have put me in? How many times can they re-escalate an application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a really long time, you're in the bottom 1%. Not much you can do though except check the call center. This is one of the reasons why I thoroughly despise the UK visa format where they've ring fenced and insulated the actual officers from the VFS

Comment: VTC: this is impossible to answer, unless one is a UKVI official.